# How to create an array of Circular Progress Bars?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I would like to know how can I create an array of Circular Progress Bars and access its properties within the array, like `CircularProgressBar[i].text` and `CircularProgressBar[i].value`.
I tried to use object array but I can't access the properties of circular progress bar within the for loop, what I also tried is to make to arrays one is type string and it has all the `CircularProgressBars.text`, and the Other one is the type INT which contains `CircularProgressBar.value`, but it didn't work, nothing changed in the form.

```
      CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar[] cbpArray = new CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar[] { shifts1.circularProgressBarNeeShift1, shifts1.circularProgressBarNeeShift2, shifts1.circularProgressBarNeeShift1 };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
    }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JwWr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since you are trying to reference an item that is in a user control you need to add an accessor inside your UserControl .cs file. I believe it is called shift1.cs for you.

Note: cpb is the name that I gave the CircularProgressBar inside the UserControl shifts1.

```
public partial class shifts1 : UserControl
{
    public CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar CPB
    {
        get
        {
            return cpb;
        }
        set
        {
            cpb = value;
        }
    }

    public shifts1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then you will use the name for each user control from your form. In my case I named mine formCPB1 and formCPB2.

```
CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar[] arr = new CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar[]
        { formCPB1.CPB, formCPB2.CPB };
```

Once you have the array you can access them by using the name of the array.

```
arr[0].Text = "test";
arr[1].Text = "asdf";
```

Comment: yeah thanks, but I encountered another problem because my
circular progress bar is in a user control when I want to access it in my public partial class form ,I got an error "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field", and if I create a static instance of this user control, the error goes away but nothing changes in the form app,

Comment: Please post some code so we can duplicate the issue.

Comment: I updated the picture you can see what I got